# ConstrainLayout ConstraintSet - not working properly with Start/End constrains

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Looks like `ConstraintSet` is finding hard to cope up with `Start/End` constrains.

This example is taken from *Google samples*.
Github: [android-ConstraintLayoutExamples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConstraintLayoutExamples)

When you replace Left & Right constrains with `Start` & `End`, ConstraintSet - not working properly, It's working with `Left/Right` constrains only.

For example replace 
layout_constraintStart_toStartOf with layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf  & replace
layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf with layout_constraintRight_toRightOf

in following files:
[constraintset_example_main.xml](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConstraintLayoutExamples/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/constraintset_example_main.xml)
[constraintset_example_big.xml](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConstraintLayoutExamples/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/constraintset_example_big.xml)

Behaviour:
[image]

**onClick of image:**

```
private ConstraintSet mConstraintSetNormal = new ConstraintSet();

private ConstraintSet mConstraintSetBig = new ConstraintSet();

public void toggleMode(View v) {
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mRootLayout);
    mShowBigImage = !mShowBigImage;
    applyConfig();
}

private void applyConfig() {
    if (mShowBigImage) {
       mConstraintSetBig.applyTo(mRootLayout);
    } else {
        mConstraintSetNormal.applyTo(mRootLayout);
    }
}
```

By default Android studio uses `start`/ `end` constrains hence it's I want to know root cause and possible fix. 
Or Is this a bug with `ConstrainSet` itself?

Comment: what is a need of replacing Left/Right with Start/End

Comment: By default Android studio uses start/ end constrains instead of Left/right.. so when I started creating new layout I found this observation and problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does look like a problem with `ConstraintSet`, but let's see. The following analysis is based upon the [`sample project`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConstraintLayoutExamples) with the link that you supplied.

In the sample project, I have updated `ConstraintLayout` to the most recent version:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5'
```

I did this in case we are trying to track down an issue that has already been addressed. I also updated the layout `constraintset_example_big` and replaced all left/right constraints with start/end constraints as follows:

**constraintset_example_big.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/activity_constraintset_example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="toggleMode"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/lake"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/lake_tahoe_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lake_tahoe_title"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/lake_discription"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

With these changes in place, this is what we see.

[image]

This is clearly not right. It is supposed to look like [`this`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlesamples/android-ConstraintLayoutExamples/master/screenshots/constraint_set_example.png) after the transition.

After some debugging, I tracked the issue down to this line in `ConstraintSetExampleActivity.java`:

```
mConstraintSetBig.load(this, R.layout.constraintset_example_big);
```

[`ConstraintSet#load()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#load(android.content.Context,%20int)) seems to be straightforward, but if we replace the code above with an explicit inflation of the layout followed by a clone of the `ConstraintSet` on the inflated layout as follows:

```
// mConstraintSetBig.load(this, R.layout.constraintset_example_big);
ConstraintLayout cl = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.constraintset_example_big,null);
mConstraintSetBig.clone(cl);
```

We see this behavior in the app which is much better.

[image]

So my takeaway is that `ConstraintSet#load()` has a problem with start/end constraints. The workaround is to inflate the `ConstraintLayout` then do a clone.

**ConstraintSetExampleActivity#onCreate()**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.constraintset_example_main);

    mRootLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_constraintset_example);
    // Note that this can also be achieved by calling
    // `mConstraintSetNormal.load(this, R.layout.constraintset_example_main);`
    // Since we already have an inflated ConstraintLayout in `mRootLayout`, clone() is
    // faster and considered the best practice.
    mConstraintSetNormal.clone(mRootLayout);
    // Load the constraints from the layout where ImageView is enlarged.

    // Toggle the comment status on the following three lines to fix/break.
    // mConstraintSetBig.load(this, R.layout.constraintset_example_big);
    ConstraintLayout cl = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.constraintset_example_big,null);
    mConstraintSetBig.clone(cl);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        boolean previous = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SHOW_BIG_IMAGE);
        if (previous != mShowBigImage) {
            mShowBigImage = previous;
            applyConfig();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with fragments at all just shows end result if I apply onVIewCreated

Answer (score 3):

This issue is known and will be fixed in the 1.1 beta 6 release

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74253269

Answer (score 2):

For those who faces issues like constraint set clone not working properly, my layout was not updating to new constraints when i called clone and applyTo methods after an api call, turns out it was due to a loading dialog i showed before the change that caused the error.